# how to access controller dataset in custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I was playing with angular js scope of custom directive  and tried to use controller dataset in custom directive with different attribute name but did not succeed. Kindly see my code and suggest me what is the proper way to access the data and set in `ng-repeat` in custom directive.

Do I need to set *ng-repeat* on custom directive or inside the directive template ? I mean

like this

```
<movie-list ng-repeat="entry in movieData" > </movie-list>
```

or inside directive template

```
<movie-list movieArray = "movieData" ></movie-list>
```

and then

```
<div>
 <ul >
     <li ng-repeat="entry in movieArray"> {{...}} </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

here is my data

### app.js

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('homeController', function($scope) {
        $scope.movieData = [{
            name : 'PK',
            star : 'Aamir Khan',
            releaseYear : '2015'
        },
        {
            name : 'PiKu',
            star : 'Irrfan Khan',
            releaseYear : '2015'
        }
        ];
});

// custom directive

angular
.module('app')
.directive('movieList', function(){
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        scope: { movieArray : '=movieArray' }, 
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $transclude) {
        },
        require: '?ngModel', 
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'movie.html',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope, element, attr, controller) {
            // console.log($scope.$parent);
        }
    };
});
```

#### index.html

```
<div ng-controller="homeController" >
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <movie-list movieArray="movieData"></movie-list>
</div>
```

#### movie.html

```
<div>
<ul class="list-group" >
    <li ng-repeat="entry in movieArray" class="list-group-item" >
        <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{ entry.name }}</h3>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">
            {{ entry.star }} - Release in {{ entry.releaseYear }}
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

`scope: { movieArray : '=movieArray' }` >> not working

`scope: { movieArray : '=movieData' }`  >> not working

even I changed the attribute

```
<movie-list movieArray="movieArray"></movie-list>
```

but not working

Comment: You need to do `<movie-list movie-array="movieData"></movie-list>` (`movie-array` instead of `movieArray`) (oh the perils of camel-snake-casing in Angular, have lost tons of time).

Comment: and what would be inside `$scope` ; `$scope : { movie-array : 'movieData' }` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update attribute name:

`<movie-list movieArray="movieData"></movie-list`>

To:

```
<movie-list movie-array="movieData"></movie-list>
```

Note: Directive or attribute name should be lower case.

Comment: and what need to write inside the `$scope` attribute ?
`scope: { movieArray : '=movieData' },` doesn't return anything

Comment: This answer is correct and based on facts from the question, where `scope: { movieArray : '=movieArray' }`. (BTW this is redundant, since the attribute and scope property names are the same, writing `scope: {movieArray: '='}` would suffice.) Where did the `scope: { movieArray : '=movieData' }` came from? And of course it doesn't work, it assigns the value of the `movie-data` attribute (which does not exist, at least according to the facts stated in the question) to the `movieArray` scope property.

Comment: I want to change controller's  `$scope.movieData` into directive's `$movieArray`

Comment: This solved my problem but why would I write   *movieArray*  instead of *movie-array* in `ng-repeat`?

Comment: This is angular syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip scope (delete  scope: { movieArray : '=movieArray' }, from your directive ) in your directive you can do that by below code in Index.html:

```
<div ng-controller="homeController" >
<div class="col-lg-6">
    < div movie-list></div>
</div>
```

And in your controller you need to replace movieData by movieArray:

```
 .controller('homeController', function($scope) {
        $scope.movieArray= [{
            name : 'PK',
            star : 'Aamir Khan',
            releaseYear : '2015'
        },
        {
            name : 'PiKu',
            star : 'Irrfan Khan',
            releaseYear : '2015'
        }
        ];
```